# i want to run a print statement x amount of times and i want it to print a diferent random letter from a given list each time

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm not sure how to print the statement in the same function without writing a crazy amount of lines:

```py
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    
print(letters[random.randint(0, 51)])
    
print(letters[random.randint(0, 51)])
```

This is what I have, but I want it to do this in the same function and have a different outcome each time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `random.choice` to pick a letter, and you can use the `string` module to not have to type them all out yourself:

```
>>> import random
>>> import string
>>> print(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase))
W
>>> def print_random_letter():
...     print(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase))
...
>>> for _ in range(10):
...     print_random_letter()
...
n
L
G
t
b
n
h
b
R
j
```

Comment: string.ascii_letters

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you say you want a different outcome each time suggests you can't just randomly choose with `random.choice`. That might get you repeats.

Instead, if you shuffle the list first, then you can merely iterate over that (at least 52 times!) to get random letters without repeat.

```
>>> import random
>>> import string
>>> letters = list(string.ascii_letters)
>>> random.shuffle(letters)
>>> letters
['b', 'U', 'N', 'F', 'l', 'd', 'x', 'A', 'h', 'o', 'j', 'T', 'Z', 'C', 'v', 'L', 'q', 'M', 'y', 't', 'r', 'u', 'R', 'B', 'E', 'm', 'k', 'n', 'c', 'i', 'S', 'V', 'K', 'H', 'Q', 'w', 'Y', 'G', 'a', 'P', 'X', 's', 'J', 'O', 'z', 'f', 'g', 'I', 'W', 'e', 'D', 'p']
```

Now, you might want to shuffle the "deck" after each choice. We can easily achieve that with a simple class that defines a custom `__iter__` function.

```
class Deck(object):
  def __init__(self, deck):
    self.deck = list(deck)
  def __iter__(self):
    while self.deck !=  []:
      random.shuffle(self.deck)
      yield self.deck.pop()
```

```
>>> print(*list(Deck(string.ascii_letters)), sep=',')
r,e,v,A,d,P,X,a,b,t,m,V,N,F,J,c,S,f,u,Z,T,g,h,j,q,p,Y,y,U,o,W,k,z,n,O,R,D,K,E,L,w,x,M,G,I,C,Q,B,i,l,H,s
>>> print(*list(Deck(string.ascii_letters)), sep=',')
g,U,Z,C,j,E,T,V,q,J,m,d,S,c,w,D,f,H,k,s,o,a,t,z,i,N,e,Y,r,n,R,O,h,v,A,K,I,l,P,B,u,F,y,L,W,G,Q,x,p,X,M,b
```